# Using ZMQ for bidirectional inter-thread communication

Tags: zeromq

I am new to ZeroMQ. I have spent the last couple of months reading the documentation and experimenting with the library. I am currently developing a multi-threaded c++ application and want to use ZeroMQ instead of mutexes to exchange data between my main thread and one of its child.

The child thread is handling the communication with an external application. Therefore, I will need to queue/sockets between the main thread and its child. One for outgoing messages and one for incoming messages.

Which zmq socket should I use in order to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to find an answer to my question. I need to use the ZMQ_PAIR  sockets. You can refer to the following documentation: http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By moving from using shared memory and mutexes to using ZeroMQ, you are entering the realm of Actor model programming.

This, in my opinion, is a fairly good thing. However, there are some things to be aware of.

1. The only reason mutexes are no longer needed is because you are copying data, not sharing it. The 'cost' is that copying a lot of data takes a lot longer than locking a mutex that points to shared data. So you can end up with a nice looking Actor model program that runs like a dog in comparison to an equivalent program that uses shared memory / mutexes.
2. A caveat is that on complicated architectures like Intel Xeons with multiple CPUs, accessing shared memory can, conceivably, take just as long as copying it. This is because this may (depending on how lucky you've been) mean transactions across the QPI bus. Actor model programming is ideal for NUMA hardware architectures. Modern Intel and AMD architectures are, partially/fundamentally, NUMA, but the protocols they run over QPI / Hypertransport "fake" an SMP environment.
3. I would avoid ZMQ_PAIR sockets wherever practicable. They don't work across network connections. This means that if, for any reason, your application needs to scale across multiple computers you have to re-write your code. However, if you use different socket types from the very beginning, a scale-up of your application is nothing more than a matter of redeploying your code, not changing it. FYI nanomsg PAIRs do not have this restriction.
4. Don't for one moment assume that Actor model programming is going to solve all your problems. It brings in a whole suite of problems all of it's own. You can still deadlock, livelock, spinlock, etc. The problem with Actor model programmes is that these problems can be lurking in your code for years and never happen, until one day the network is just a little bit busier and -bam- your program stops running...
5. However, there is a development of Actor model programming called "Communicating Sequential Processes". This doesn't solve those problems, but if you've written your program with these problems they are guaranteed to happen every single time. So you discover the problem during development and testing, not five years later. There's also a process calculi for it, i.e. you can algebraically prove that your design is problem free before you ever write a single line of code. ZeroMQ is not CSP. Interestingly CSP is making something of a comeback - the Rust and Go languages both do CSP. However, they do not do CSP across network connections - it's all in-process stuff. Erlang does CSP too, and AFAIK does it across network connections.
6. Assuming you've read all that about CSP and are still going to use ZeroMQ, think carefully about what it is you are planning on sending across the ZeroMQ sockets. If it's all within one program on the same machine, then sending copies of, for example, arrays of integers is fine. They'll still be interpretable as integers at the receiving end. However, if you have aspirations to send data through ZMQ sockets to another computer it's well worth considering some sort of serialisation technology. ZeroMQ delivers messages. Why not make those messages the byte stream from an object serialiser? Then you can guarantee that the received message will, after de-serialisation, mean something appropriate at the receiving end, instead of having to solve problems with endianness, etc.
7. Favourite serialisers for me include Google Protocol Buffers. It is language / operating system agnostic, giving lots of options for a heterogeneous system. ASN.1 is another really good option, it can be got for most of the important languages, and it has a rich set of wire formats (including XML and, now/soon, JSON, which gives some interesting inter-op options), and does Constraints (something Google PBufs don't do), but does tend to cost money if one wants really good tools for it. XML can be understood by almost anything, but is bloated. Basically it's worth picking one that doesn't tie you down to using, say, C#, or Python everywhere.

Good luck!

Comment: As always, @bazza, wonderfull inventory of design aspects that every distributed computing architect has to bear in mind. **Excellent job!**

Comment: Thank your for your detailed answer. I will read more on CSP to see if it can improve my architecture.